# One of the parameters from ActionLink doesn't pass to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with MVC5.

- One of parameters (`nrAccount`) passes to controller
- another parameter (`manualDate`) doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

#### View

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Update", "Home"))" method="post">
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Account)
    </td>
    <td class="choice">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.PaymentDate, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control datepicker" })
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.ActionLink("Save", "Update", "Home", new { nrAccount = item.Account, manualDate = item.PaymentDate },null)
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

#### Controller Action

```cs
public ActionResult Update(string nrAccount, DateTime? manualDate)
{
    _docs.Update(manualDate, nrAccount);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

#### The `Update` of `_docs`

```
public void Update(DateTime? manualDate, string nrAccount)
{
    var toUpdate = GetByAccount(nrAccount);

    toUpdate.DATE_MANUAL = manualDate;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}

public IEnumerable<CustomersTable> GetAll()
{
    return _context.CustomersTable;
}

public CustomersTable GetByAccount(string nrAccount)
{
    return GetAll().FirstOrDefault(k => k.FOPKTO_ACCOUNT_ == nrAccount);
}
```

No errors comes up, just nothing is saved to db. When I debug my code I can't see date passed to variable `manualDate`, don't know why. But `nrAccount` is passed correctly.

User can choose date one DatePicker:

[image]

Comment: Can you check changing `@Html.ActionLink("Save", "Update", "Home", new { nrAccount = item.Account, manualDate = item.PaymentDate },null)` with `<input type="submit"  value="Submit"/>`?

Comment: If you change your datetime to not be nullable does it work?

Comment: @noobprogrammer ok but how can I add routing parameters to submit?

Comment: @Ben I don't think I can. I return to my Model (which is then passed to View) a few date columns which have nulls in database so I needed to make them nullable in Model.

Comment: it still doesn't work. I need to pass value from textbox to controller. Almost all values in db in column ManualDate are nulls, that's why here returns null and passes this null to controller. Question is how can I pass value (date picked by user)  from this TextBox to controller , how can I do that?

Comment: @Muska Is `item.PaymentDate` a nullable type?

Comment: @Ben yes, it is.

Comment: @Ben I need to add one thing - ```item.Payment``` is null everywhere in the column in the database. SO I return null to my web form, no values shows up in cells. And then, using datapicker in ```item.Payment``` field, a user can choose a date. And I want to take this date (from ```ite.PaymentDate```), pass it to the controller and save to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a GET request when you should be using a POST.  And your GET contains the account but not the date from your date textbox because it only contains the initial value not the value that the user changes it to.  So to fix you should change your GET to a post by making the following changes.

Correct your form action, it has one too may brackets, i.e. `@Url.Action("Update", "Home")` and not `@Url.Action("Update", "Home"))`

Add an `HttpPost` attribute to your `Update` method in the controller.

As mentioned in the comments replace your @Action.Link, that will result in a GET, with a submit button that will result in a POST.

So that you get the account number add a hidden field for that.

And finally because of the way your textboxfor works you will need to change your update method to receive an object which has properties for `Account` and `PaymentDate`.

Here is some demo code that is very similar to yours to show you what I mean.

The viewModel

```
    public class HomeViewModel
    {
        public string Account { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PaymentDate { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var item = new HomeViewModel
            {
                Account = "theAccountNumber",
                PaymentDate = null
            };

            var viewModel = new List<HomeViewModel>()
            {
                item
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }       

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(HomeViewModel item)
        {
            //call your _docs method here  
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

The view (note the hidden field for Account)

```
@model List<AccountDate.Controllers.HomeViewModel>

<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <form action="@Url.Action("Update", "Home")" method="post">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Account)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Account)      

                </td>
                <td class="choice">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.PaymentDate, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control datepicker" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />                     
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    }
</table>
```

Following my example when Save is clicked all the data in the form will be posted to the server and be put into the model using the default model binding as required.

Comment: I try this using BeginForm. Unfortunately, still sth going wrong and nulls are returned. I'll talk to developers in my company. Anyways, thanks for help!